# applicationWillTerminate / ApplicationDidEnterBackground issues

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I need your help to solve this.

I found a tutorial on how to save/load gamestate [Save Game State Tutorial](http://www.71squared.com/2009/12/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-12-saving-state/) and I think I did quite well on my own but I got stuck.

First of all this is what I need to save upon moving the game into the background and upon exiting the game.

*Playerscore

*Highscore

*Level

*Time

*the grid and the bricks on it (the grid is 6x6 and I have 35 bricks on it that are movable inside the grid) //don't know how to save/load this part

*amount of rubies

*the state of settings, if the music button as well as the SFX button is on or off //don't know how to save/load this part

*the state of the music, is it at the beginning of the song or middle etc when tehg ame stopped //don't know how to save/load this part

I don't know how to load the game in a paused state with the Ready, Set, Go images to appear before starting from where the user left off. (don't know how to connect them to applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationWillTerminate in my UIApplicationDelegate, same with the save part)

Then I want also the main menu to known if there is a saved gamestate and let the user decide between a new game and continue.

the code below shows how I did in the mainmenu.m file and in my gameview.m file. Let me know if you want to see the gamecontroller as well...

**mainmenu.h**
    //Game Controller
    GameController *sharedGameController;

**mainmenu.m**

```
//The game begins either by continue or by resetting the gamestate
-(IBAction)start{

    NSLog(@"Start");

    newgame.hidden = NO;

    if(sharedGameController.resumedGameAvailable == YES){
        //IF there is a gamestate saved then activate the continue button
        continuegame.hidden = YES;
        continuegame.alpha = 1.0;
        continuegame.enabled = YES;
    }
    else{

        continuegame.hidden = NO;
        continuegame.alpha = 0.5;
        continuegame.enabled = NO;

    }
    korridor1.hidden = NO;
    fackla.hidden = NO;
    Start.hidden = YES;
    option.hidden = YES;
    howtoplay.hidden = YES;
    SFXimage.hidden = YES; 
    Musicimage.hidden = YES; 
    back.hidden = NO;

}

//Continue previous game
-(IBAction)ContinueGame{

    [audio stop];
    audio.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [audio release];
    NSLog(@"Continue");

    back.hidden = YES;
    newgame.hidden = YES;
    continuegame.hidden = YES;
    korridor1.hidden = NO;
    fackla.hidden = YES;
    Start.hidden = YES;
    option.hidden = YES;
    howtoplay.hidden = YES;
    SFXimage.hidden = YES; 
    Musicimage.hidden = YES;  
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"korridor_1.png" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    korridor1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(13,13);
    korridor1.alpha = 1.0f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];


    //The Game begins
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5 target:self selector:@selector(GameView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

**gameview.m**

```
//Load the saved gamestate
- (void)loadGameState {

    // Set up the file manager and documents path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; NSMutableData *gameData;
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *decoder;
    NSString *documentPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gameState.dat"];
    gameData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:documentPath]; 
    decoder = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:gameData];
    NSLog(@"INFO - GameScene: Loading saved game duration."); 
    //timeSinceGameStarted = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"timeSinceGameStarted"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"INGO - GameScene: Loading saved game score."); 
    playerscore = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"playerscore"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"INGO - GameScene: Loading saved high score."); 
    highscore = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"highscore"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"INGO - GameScene: Loading saved level."); 
    level = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Level"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"INGO - GameScene: Loading saved amount of rubies."); 
    totalrubies = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"totalrubies"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"INFO - GameScene: Loading game time data."); 
    [decoder release];
}

//Saving the current gamestate
-(void)saveGameState {

    NSLog(@"Saving game state");

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *gameStatePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gameState.dat"];

    NSMutableData *gameData; 
    NSKeyedArchiver *encoder; 
    gameData = [NSMutableData data]; 
    encoder = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:gameData];

    // Archive the games timer settings
    NSNumber *savedGameStartTime = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalSeconds]; 
    //NSNumber *savedTimeSinceGameStarted = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:timeSinceGameStarted]; 
    // Archive the players score
    NSNumber *savedPlayerScore = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:playerscore];
    // Archive the games high score
    NSNumber *savedHighScore = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:highscore];
    // Archive the current game level
    NSNumber *savedcurrentlevel = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:level];
    // Archive the total amount of rubies
    NSNumber *savedTotalRubies = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalrubies];

    [encoder encodeObject:savedGameStartTime forKey:@"gameStartTime"];
    //[encoder encodeObject:savedTimeSinceGameStarted forKey:@"timeSinceGameStarted"];

    [encoder encodeObject:savedPlayerScore forKey:@"playerscore"]; 
    [encoder encodeObject:savedHighScore forKey:@"highscore"]; 

    [encoder encodeObject:savedcurrentlevel forKey:@"Level"]; 

    [encoder encodeObject:savedTotalRubies forKey:@"totalrubies"];

    // Finish encoding and write the contents of gameData to file
    [encoder finishEncoding]; 
    [gameData writeToFile:gameStatePath atomically:YES]; 
    [encoder release];

    // Tell the game controller that a resumed game is available
    sharedGameController.resumedGameAvailable = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a nstimer that makes it go ready, set, go, then if go is not hidden then you have your non paused gameState

Comment: I already have that. I thought if there was another way when it came to load from the load gamestate...